# Will using the positive end of an AA battery to touch my phone screen damage my phone?

Tags: touchscreen, smartphones

I'm playing a game where it will be helpful to hold down a button for an extended period of time. I didn't have a stylus, so I looked online for any ideas. Lots of people said to use the negative end of an AA battery. It works, but only when you're touching the battery. So I tried the positive end of the battery on my phone's touch screen, and it works (even when I'm not touching the battery). I haven't seen anything online about this, which I found very unusual.

So my question is, will it damage my phone if I use the positive end of an AA battery on my phone screen?

Comment: No, it will not.

Comment: I concur with @DKNguyen

Comment: Not electrically, but it's metal so it could cause mechanical damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitive touch screens works sensing the electric field being driven toward ground by a finger… or whatever has the electrical properties of a finger.

You are non making any current flow and except for the risks of scratching (and blunt damage) there are no issues. They also sell 'touch styli' which are more or less pieces of metal tube

Answer (score 0):

Pressure = force/area = weight/area, hence more pressure when the + end is resting on screen.